# dropping the backing table drops the materialized view

Tags: postgresql

When dropping a backing table for a materialized view, is it normal for the materialized view to be also dropped? I understand that the materialized view is invalid without the presence of the backing table, but dropping the materialized view seems a bit unusual.

The materialized views is created as follows

```
create materialized view if not exists ea_master.geography_hierarchy
as
Select 
 parent.geography_id  as parent_geography_id
 ,child.geography_id  as child_geography_id
from ea_master.Geography parent
join ea_master.Polygon pParent on pParent.polygon_id = parent.polygon_id 
join ea_master.Polygon pChild on ST_Contains(pParent.geometry, pChild.geometry)
join ea_master.Geography child on child.polygon_id  = pChild.polygon_id 
with no data;
```

The query used to drop the backing table: `DROP TABLE ea_master.geography CASCADE;`

Please note at some point the materialized view is refreshed with data before issuing the command to drop the backing table.

Comment: `DROP TABLE ea_master.geography CASCADE;` does exactly what you told it do, drop dependent objects per [Drop Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptable.html): "CASCADE Automatically drop objects that depend on the table (such as views), and in turn all objects that depend on those objects ".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Raptélan on postgres-slack channel, who pointed to me the documentation for `delete table` with `cascade` parameter. As per the docs, it is expected behavior from the docs excerpt:

```
DROP TABLE always removes any indexes, rules, triggers, and constraints that exist 
for the target table. However, to drop a table that is referenced by a view or a 
foreign-key constraint of another table, CASCADE must be specified. (CASCADE will 
remove a dependent view entirely, but in the foreign-key case it will only remove 
the foreign-key constraint, not the other table entirely.)
```

Unfortunately looks like the cascade parameter is required to remove the backing table to ensure view is removed along with it. I will just have to recreate the view every time the backing table is deleted with the cascade option.

Also, I was conflating this cascade parameter to the foreign keys with `on delete cascade` parameter.

Comment: The question is why drop the table at all if you are going to recreate it later? Why not just `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` the data?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, it was primarily to recreate parts of the schema. I think I have learned not to drop the table and alter the table with schema changes.